# Mysql SUM() TIME wrong format

Tags: mysql, time, sum

I'm calculating the sum of two columns from the same table with `SUM()` but the end result is an integer (`286676`). I'm guessing it's milliseconds? How can I convert to `TIME`(00:00:00)?

**database**

```
id|hours_worked | hours_worked_wk2 |
```

**hours_worked** = 14:33:38 
**hours_worked_wk2** = 14:33:38

**Query**

```
SELECT *,SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ep.hours_worked)))+SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ep.hours_worked_wk2))) 
AS TotalHoursWorked 
FROM employeepayroll ep 
JOIN employees em ON ep.employee_id=em.employee_id 
JOIN payroll p ON ep.payroll_id=p.payroll_id 
JOIN payrolltaxes pt ON ep.payroll_id=pt.payroll_id 
WHERE ep.timesheet_status='Approved' AND p.pay_group='26' 
ORDER BY ep.payroll_id DESC
```

**TotalHoursWorkd** = 286676

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula.

```
hours = cast(duration_in_milliseconds \ (60 * 60 * 1000) as int)  
mins = (duration_in_milliseconds \ (60 * 1000)) mod 60  
secs = (duration_in_milliseconds \ 1000) mod 60
```

Your query will look something like this:

```
select cast(duration_in_milliseconds\(60*60*1000) as int)+':'((duration_in_milliseconds \ (60*1000)) mod 60;)+':'((duration_in_milliseconds \ 1000) mod 60) from something
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I just gave you the formula :)
You can personally edit it in your query.

Comment: Well thanks dude but I`m really simplistic in my learning right now. How do I use that with my original query loll?

Answer (score 0):

When you see it...

```
14:33:38 >>> 143,338 × 2 = 286,676
```

Yikes.  The numbers in the times are being implicitly cast to integers.

You are adding the two values of `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(...))+SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(...))`.

Instead, use `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(...) + SUM(...))`.